# Is there any way to declare a array, not just its elements, as const?

Tags: c++, c++20

Using `std::array` I can declare both the array itself and it's objects as const.

```
const std::array<const int,2> a {1,2};
```

However, if I read the standard correctly, a declaration such as this only declares the array elements const. See [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.array#5)

```
const int a[2] {1,2};
```

The reason this matters is that if the complete object, in these cases `a`, is const then it's UB to alter any subobjects. If only the subobjects, like `a[0]` are const then they can be modified by "transparent replacement" and it's not UB. This is a new change in basic.life as of c++20. See [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8). It's also clear from the definition of arrays that array elements are subobjects. See [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#2)

For instance this would be legal if the complete object (total array) wasn't const.

```
std::construct_at(&a[0], 5);
```

So is there any way other than using the `std::array` wrapper to declare the complete array const?

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.type.qualifier#3

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  Thanks. That makes sense but I'd missed it. Please write it as an answer.

Comment: Note this is a change from the older "Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type" rule. Not sure when exactly it happened, possibly post-c++17.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. In c++14: [Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type ([dcl.array]).](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.type.qualifier#2) which contradicts this (An array type whose elements are cv-qualified is also considered to have the same cv-qualifications as its elements.)[https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.type.qualifier#5] Not only are standards long but they are inconsistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the variable declared in

```
const int a[2] {1,2};
```

is "*array of 2 `const int`*" per the rule you linked, but that itself is a `const`-qualified type by the resolution of [CWG 1059](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1059.html), which can be found in [[basic.type.qualifier]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.type.qualifier#3.sentence-1) of the post-C++20 draft:

> An array type whose elements are cv-qualified is also considered to have the same cv-qualifications as its elements.

I don't think there are any `const`-qualified array types to non-`const`-qualified elements, nor non-`const`-qualified array types to `const`-qualified elements, although I guess the object replacement rules allow placing elements of different cv-qualification into an array under some circumstances.

So `a` is already a `const` complete object and modifying it in the suggested way would be UB.

Comment: Wrapping a built in const array in a non-const `std::array` would meet the requirements that allow changing the non-const elements via the basic.life rule. But not built in arrays that were not subobjects.